# Change validation-error class only for selected elements (Jquery validation)

Tags: jquery, html, css, validation

I dynamically add file upload input fields and attach jquery validation to them. When the error span tag appears, it's having 150px left value which I cannot change because it affects the other fields which has validation errors. Is there a way to change css attributes for "validation-error" class for a specific elements chosen ( like element names starts with

```
element.attr("name").startsWith("claim[travelExpense][travelExpenseAttachment]")
```

etc. I only need to change the class and not the place of the span tag

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

You can use `^=` operator which means *starts with*

For example:

```
 $( "input[name^='news']" ).val( "news here!" );
```

It will match all inputs whose attibute starts with *news*

Comment: I need a way to change the ""validation-error" class for some elements I know to write selectors but dont know how to change error css class messages of Jquery form validation plugin

Answer (score 0):

I did this like below,

,
        showErrors: function(errorMap, errorList) {
            this.defaultShowErrors();

```
        $.each( errorMap, function( key, value ) {

           if ( $('[name="'+key+'"]').attr("name").startsWith("claim[travelExpense][travelExpenseAttachment]") )
               {
                   var id = $('[name="'+key+'"]').attr('id');
                   var intPart = id.split("_")[1];
                   $("#haveFile_"+intPart+"-error").css('left','1px');
                   //$("#haveFile_"+intPart+"-error").css('position','relative');
                   $("#haveFile_"+intPart+"-error").css('top','24px');
                   //$("#haveFile_"+intPart+"-error").css('margin','0');
               }
        });

    //alert('not valid!')
    },
    success: function() {
        //alert('valid!')
    }
```